# TypeScript template literal types and infer works together somehow?

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain me the code below, it is not like I have any problem here. But, I wanna know why is it working.

How come this CREATETYPE knows that namespace is undefined or not, thus creates the correct type ?

```
type CREATETYPE<K extends string, NS extends string> = NS extends `${infer NS}` ? `${NS}/${K}` : K;

function generateDynamicTypes<T extends string, NS extends string>(keys: T[], namespace?: NS): { [K in T]: CREATETYPE<K, NS> } {
  const namespacePrefix: string = namespace ? `${namespace}/` : '';

  return keys.reduce((res, key) => {
    res[key] = `${namespacePrefix}${key}`;
    return res;
  }, Object.create(null));
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html

Comment: Please consider modifying the title of this question to summarize your question, as described in [ask].  Right now it is quite vague.

Comment: I'd say it is super vague)))

Comment: I hope it explains more now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is the compiler cannot infer from `string` to a template literal type.  I will unpack that in the long answer below:

---

The `CREATETYPE` type alias is using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) as introduced in TypeScript 4.1.  The code here is a bit weird and not the way I'd approach it.  And the particular behavior you're asking about doesn't seem to be explicitly documented, but I'll try to explain what's happening.

---

Note that if you call `generateDynamicTypes()` without a `namespace` argument, the compiler has no value from which to infer the `NS` type parameter.  As such, the inference fails, and the compiler defaults to inferring it as its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  In this case, it is `string`:

```
generateDynamicTypes(["a", "b"])
// function generateDynamicTypes<"a" | "b", string>(...)
```

On the other hand, if you specify a string literal value for `namespace`, the compiler will infer `NS` to be the [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) of that value, so:

```
generateDynamicTypes(["a", "b"], "ns")
// function generateDynamicTypes<"a" | "b", "ns">(...)
```

This is one place where I probably wouldn't write the code this way, because if `namespace` really is a `string` without being a known string literal, the output type will be incorrect:

```
const oops = generateDynamicTypes(["a", "b"], "oopsie".toUpperCase());
/* const oops: {
    a: "a";
    b: "b";
} */
```

The type of `"oopsie".toUpperCase()` is just `string` according to the compiler, not the actual literal value `"OOPSIE"`.  So the compiler says the output property values will just be `"a"` and `"b"` whereas you'll get `"OOPSIE/a"` and `"OOPSIE/b"` at runtime.  This mismatch is an edge case and maybe nobody cares about it?  But moving on.

---

So your question becomes: why does `CREATETYPE<K, NS>`, defined as

```
type CREATETYPE<K extends string, NS extends string> =
  NS extends `${infer NS}` ? `${NS}/${K}` : K;
```

take the "true" branch of the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) when `NS` is a string literal like `"ns"`, but the "false" branch when `NS` is just `string`, as in:

```
type PrefixedA = CREATETYPE<"a", "ns"> // "ns/a"
type JustA = CREATETYPE<"a", string> // "a"
```

Before we go on, I'm going to change the definition to

```
type CREATETYPE<K extends string, NS extends string> =
  NS extends `${infer NS2}` ? `${NS2}/${K}` : K;
```

which is identical in behavior, but highlights the fact that `infer NS2` introduces a new type parameter; in the original code, this was shadowing the previous value of `NS`.  I personally wouldn't shadow type parameters for this case.

---

If we look at the pull request introducing template literal types, [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336), there is this in the description:

> Type inference supports inferring from a string literal type to a template literal type. [...details about matching elided...] Some examples:
>
> ```
>  type MatchPair<S extends string> = S extends `[${infer A},${infer B}]` ? [A, B] : unknown;
>  type T20 = MatchPair<'[1,2]'>;  // ['1', '2']
> ```

So `` NS extends `${infer NS2}` ? ... `` should try to match the whole input string as the inferred value of `NS2`.  That means `NS2`, if inferred, will just be equal to `NS`, and the whole thing looks like a no-op.  And indeed, when `NS` is a string literal type like `"a"`, this is what happens.

So again, why does `` string extends `${infer NS2}` ? ... `` not work?  Why doesn't `NS2` get inferred as `string`?  Here is where the documentation isn't explicit.  Again, it says:

> Type inference supports inferring from a **string literal type** to a template literal type.

The fact that the documentation makes sure to say that inference from a string literal type works seems to imply that inference from the non-literal `string` type won't work... but it doesn't say this in so many words.  You can look at [the relevant line in the PR diff](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336/files#diff-d9ab6589e714c71e657f601cf30ff51dfc607fc98419bf72e04f6b0fa92cc4b8R20007) (you need to view large diffs to see this) and confirm, however, that the compiler *only* tries to infer into a template literal type if the source type is a string literal.

So there you go!

---

If I were going to write this code, I'd probably first change it to not rely on undocumented behavior.  Perhaps like this:

```
type CREATETYPE2<K extends string, NS extends string> =
  string extends NS ? `${NS}/${K}` : K;
```

And furthermore, I'd tease apart the `undefined` from the `string` case, maybe like this:

```
function generateDynamicTypes2<
  T extends string, NS extends string | undefined = undefined
>(
  keys: T[],
  namespace?: NS
): { [K in T]: NS extends undefined ? K : `${NS}/${K}` } {
  // same impl
}

generateDynamicTypes2(["a"]) // {a: "a"}
generateDynamicTypes2(["a"], "ns") // {a: "ns"/ a}
generateDynamicTypes2(["a"], "oopsie".toUpperCase()); // { a: `${string}/a` }
```

Looks reasonable to me now.  The type `${string}/a` just means "I only know this string ends with `"/a"`", which corresponds pretty well to what is coming out of that function in the case where `namespace` is only known to be  `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQEQE8xsBbGCAFUIAdUBnAHksVQA88wATexeqTDDDIANIgByAZVYd0PPgKHIAfAAoA1qkL0AXIkoBtALpiSpBjWwRUAfj1SAlHoDeiAwGlEQ-Ub0BhACUAUQBBSiDKAE0ABSDGdzEpZUQAX0RnAChERAgEfkQzCytUaMxUYBg2PX5BYUQAXgKyIutEG0QAAwASZ0L6S2sUgHoOxD0AcnGAbgysxDKoEEwkTW0AOjKuEGtVVTL6MVWHBuTM7Oz9g1WjBs6evoGSsoq2FJ7VlI6Z8-nUReXfvRvqkxAB5ABGACtUNA1hAyrhUKowCAADaohwOGYpWZoDA4PBEMwUah0eiqAwAImwlLElPBlKMDgyQyGiFAkFgCBQ6CwiKJZBJtAYjGplMQAB9EPTaQpaipVGslcyMni+YTiIKqMLyVSaXSGSZpWB6JTmaz2eBoPAkGqCQRNeRtWTRTTJdKGXSTZS1Eq1irciaoIg4HAaLxGnb+Y6hWSKWKDYy6aHwzBUJS1lA4ABVGh0TB+bD0JGYmZDABUOTywZTunSc2y2D0YuB2XBzYZ2MQ5aGswyUGFiECoXCUVi8RknHkNSUiWk7CnvBnwmS9TmUkncl43WcQmAWAkkgATJ82ndnFIT0Meu5T3p3DN+4PSuVKqguCFbsOwhEYnEE8aprJBalImkMNJPnQiAAFIgPwn6NN+o5-q6srLioiAgRBkGoEOwQ-mOQRHhOC5bnKs6Hpu3BLooK4NHM6FUfIG7tDuUjDDed6IA+swcta3JRhqxLOgwxEsKR1HkcIc5MTR8ruuAXCvhgXC3IpynvmocyrHWhgmHMDzFHYh4ZE46RuJ43iUL4lESfI6kVCpZ6eHobGSBxzi3qMaRnFWQZNOY-TFC+LzVLRyC3IZrSsfczRBYMIxjIgkzAgsSwrFo9AbO+2xInsDCHFoxz1KcDaAlcWg3I0O5RU8r6vO8WifK2vz-Eg+zAikYJQjCUBwgieDImiGJYhkOKqry9oCk6pKifGNJMphbLOE20o0jigkOsJs30Ee81JoBZpLekq2gaabLYBtk3RttOp7XqB2UrWaYZlmub5oWxaqKWx3ZK4q07uhwzYN5GRAA)

Comment: namespace is suppose to be string literal so, there is nothing wrong with that. But, do you think we can force it to be a string literal?

Comment: I think prolonged but great explanation. Last part is very much satisfying, thanks

Comment: If you want to disallow `string` it's possible but not pretty... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/eweVaN); the `generateDynamicTypes2()` in the link now rejects a `namespace` that's a `string` with an error like `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StringLiteralType | undefined'`, which is great except there's really no useful type named `StringLiteralType`.